# Why does incrementation of pointer or value leads to the same result in a loop

Tags: c++, pointers

Moin Moin,

Currently I'm learning c++ and have an interesting effect which I can't explain to myself.

Why does `*iterator++;` also work in this situation?

From my point of view it should increase the value to the pointer of. Does this mean that the `++` operator of the returned object from `std::begin(feld)` is overridden to handle this to make it comfortable? I'm confused

```
void CArrayExamples::beginAndEndMethod()
{
    int feld[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    
    int* iterator = std::begin(feld);
    int* ending = std::end(feld);

    while (iterator != ending)
    {
        std::cout << "iterator:" << iterator << std::endl;
        std::cout << "*iterator:" << *iterator << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ending:" << ending << std::endl;
        std::cout << "*ending:" << *ending << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

        //why does this both work? :D
        //*iterator++;
        iterator++;
        //TODO: Ask somebody!

    }
}
```

Comment: Operator Precedence

Comment: *ending is undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah -- that's a **post** increment; the value of the expression `iterator++` is the **old** value of `iterator`, so `*iterator` and `*iterator++` have the same value. `*++iterator` would result in the value in the new location being used. You're right, though about the general logic.

Comment: @Incomputable didnt got you. what means "undefined behavior"?

Answer (score 1):

The increment operator `++` has higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`, so `*iterator++` is interpreted as `*(iterator++)`, i.e. increment the iterator/pointer and return the value pointed to by the old value.

Your code does not use the returned value, though.

If you want to increment the value, not the iterator/pointer, write `(*iterator)++`.